# Why does this code output '49,50,51' when i expect it to output 1,2,3

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("please enter a number");
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scn.nextInt();


        String jam = Integer.toString(x);
        int[] azure = new int[jam.length()];

        //  Char[] character = new Char[jam.length()];
        String java = Integer.toString(x);
        for(char g :java.toCharArray()){
            int i = -1;
            i++;
           int m = (int)g;
           azure[i] = m;

            System.out.println(azure[i]);
           // System.out.println(g);
        }
    }
}
```

when I enter the number 123 I expect individual numbers 1, 2, 3 to display, I know if I just output g then it works but I want to store the individual numbers in an array... but I keep getting weird results around 50 like 49,50,51
This is the most bizarre output I have encountered so far lol....
please help...

Comment: Look at the Javadoc for String.toCharArray.

Comment: Those are the ASCII value of 1,2,3 respectively. Subtract each character with '0' to get their real values.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert `char` into `int` use `Character.getNumericValue(g)`

`int m = (int)g` will not assign 1,2 or 3 to `m` instead it will receive the ASCII value of `1,2,3` which is `49,50,51` respectively. This also happens when you perform addition and subtraction on numeric `char`. So you an use this trick also to solve your problem. Meaning you can write like this and it would fix your issue-
`int m = g-'0'`